# How to show two html tables using different table id's?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display two html tables using different table id's. I am able to display one table but I am not able to display the second table and not figure it out where I am making error.

Code is given below:

```js
var $container = $("#container");
 
 
 var $row = $("#container table tbody tr");

 // Loop through items in JSON data..
   var $button = $("<button>" + 'xyz' + "</button>");
   $container.prepend($button);
   var table = $("<table1>");
   table.append($("<tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>"));
          
  // Button click handler..
   $button.on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   for( var i=0; i<2; i++) {
     
     // Replace row HTML..
     //parent row
     var row=$('<tr ><td>' + 'data' + '</td>' +  + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
     
     table.append(row);
     
     for(var j =0; j<2; j++) {
     
     var row=$('<tr><td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
     $('<td>data</td>')
          .on('click', function() { 
          //I want to display table2 when clicked on col2 data
          
          var table = $("<table2>");
   
          table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr   >"));
          var row=$('<tr><td>' + 'data' + '</td>' +  + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
          table.append(row);
          
          })
          .appendTo(row);
          table.append(row);
          $("#table2").html(table);
     }
 }    
     
    
     $("#table1").html(table);
   


     // Show table if it's not already visible..
     

   });
```

```css
#table2 {
   margin-top: 20px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   width: 500px;
 }


#table1 {
   margin-top: 20px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid silver;
   width: 500px;
 }

#table1 th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: left;
 }
#table1 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  }
#table1 tr {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  
 button {
   margin-left: 15px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
   <div id="table1">
   </div>

 </div>
 
   <div id="table2">
   </div>
```

I want to show second table when i click on values of column2. Kindly guide me how to fix this issue. 
Here is the full code- https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/styjk9vr/48/

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: Do you need the appending the row on second table when the row is clicked

Comment: when  the col2 is clicked, i want to show second table  that is table2

Comment: after on click col2 data , i want to display table2 content beside table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first append the table column values after that apply `click` event on the last column.

Try below code or go through [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy4kze5q/2/)

```js
var $container = $("#container");
var m = ['data','data1'];

// Loop through items in JSON data..
var $button = $("<button>" + 'xyz' + "</button>");
$container.prepend($button);
var table = $("<table>");
table.append($("<tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>"));

// Button click handler..
$button.on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    // Replace row HTML..
    //parent row
    var row = $('<tr ><td>' + 'data' + '</td><td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');

    table.append(row);

    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      //child row
      var row = $('<tr><td>' + "" + '</td><td>' + m[j] + '</td></tr>');
      $(row).find('td:last').on('click', function() {
        // second table
        var tempData = $(this).text();
        var table2 = $("<table>");

        table2.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr   >"));
        var row = $('<tr class="parent_row" ><td>' + tempData + '</td>' + +'<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
        table2.append(row);
        $("#table2").html(table2);
      })
      table.append(row);
    }
  }


  $("#table1").html(table);



  // Show table if it's not already visible..


});
```

```css
#table2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 500px;
}

#table1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 500px;
}

#table1 th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

#table1 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

#table1 tr {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

button {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="table1">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="table2">
</div>
```

Comment: I need one help

Comment: $(row).find('td:last').on , is not collecting live data ,array data,i have a array of data to put into table2 , but it is showing undefined values?

Comment: Can you show me the code with array data? @AbhaySingh

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/styjk9vr/95/ , i want that on click data , it will show some information , and on click data1 , it will show another information

Comment: Please check I have updated my answer. Now it returns the column data when you click on it. @AbhaySingh

Comment: How to capture current value of column1  inside click fucntion of col2, can you please tell me?

Comment: I didn't get your point, could you please tell me in detail that what you actually looking for? @AbhaySingh

Comment: suppose when i click on data1of column2 , i want to get its parent row i.e column1 value,

Comment: $this.parent() something like that of table1

Comment: If you click a column `td` and you want to get its parent row then you just do `$('td').closest('tr')` and after getting the row you can use `find` method to get your desired column element in that row. @AbhaySingh

Comment: find(td:first) would work if i want to get column1 of parent row?

Comment: but it is showing all the rows when i use $('td').closest('tr') in my click function but i want its parent row only

Comment: You can just pass `this` in place of `td` when you click the column value like this `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: var r = $(this).closest('tr')
 var text1 = $(r).find('td:first'); console.log(text1); , this is not working

Comment: Could you please make a working demo of it so I can help you better in that case?

Comment: You just change this line `$(r).find('td:first').text();` to get text value from first column. In your demo code if you write this line it should give you the column1 value that is empty. But if the first column filled with some value then it will return that value to you.

Comment: But i want its parent column1 value which is not empty?

Comment: But in your case, if 3rd-row 2nd-column value click then its previous row column1 value is empty. So, what exactly you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201660/discussion-between-shubham-baranwal-and-abhay-singh).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors are obsolete today (i.e. they can't produce live collections). `$('<td>data</td>')` will give you empty result, so no onclick is added. This will give you your desired collection:

```
table1.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(2)")
```

`td:nth-child(2)` selects cells of second column on the called object (table1). Then you can hook the onclick event in loop to every item in the collection.

Comment: $('<td>data</td>') is not collecting live data, i have array of data but it is not collecting it, can you please help me?

Comment: It is showing undefined, i have array of data to make table2 but when i am looping through it, it is showing undefined values

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav10022/styjk9vr/95/ , i want that on click data , it will show some information , and on click data1 , it will show another information